# How do I implement EntityFramework.Partitioned Views

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, partitioned-view

So, I've been trying to implement EntityFramework.PartitionedViews all day and I'm not really any further than when I started.

My problem is that I collect large quantities of data (scores of millions of rows per month), so want to partition the data so that it's maintainable as the tables grow. I've found a class library that does this but I'm not really sure how to implement it.

The guide I've been using is:
http://datumstream.ca/blog/index.php/2016/05/18/big-data-partitioned-views-using-entity-framework/

The library is https://github.com/GiscardGirard/EntityFramework.PartitionedViews

My issue is that I don't even know where to start. It says that a DbContext should be created for each table, but not how one goes about this. Normally when creating a new db I just create a context and I know how to do that, but creating several contexts at once is more problematic; where do I write the code that implements this?

The guide basically says:

- Create partitioned view config
- Register a type with a DbContext (but only shows the method provided in the library)
- Create partitioned views

It doesn't provide any sample code and i'm super confused. If anyone has any experience with this and can point me in the right direction of how I create my context. How I create the tables (I have three non-relational tables that need going in this azure SQL DB), would I create a library for a context and then have contexts held inside that?

Comment: I create the Database in SQL first.  Then use the VS tools to map Entity Classes from the Database.

Comment: hey @jdweng, appreciate the comment. Don't suppose you could you could help me out with a little code sample to help me on my way :)

Comment: Usually modifying tables in a database is not done frequently.   So I either manually build my databases in SQL Server Management Studio or CREATE a query in SSMS to build the tables.I then use VS menu to connect to the data source and create the Entity classes.